# Were Rama and Lakshmana the only humans who fought in the Ramayana war?

Tags: ramayana, rama, war, lakshmana

We have these beings called Rakshasas on Ravana's side and monkeys and bears on Rama's side.  I don't recall reading about any humans beside Rama and Lakshmana fighting on either side.  For that matter, its not clear if Rama and Lakshmana ran into any humans after the abduction of Sita until they came back to Ayodhya.

Answer (score 8):

Rama and Lakshmana are the only two humans who fought the war. No humans besides Rama and Lakshmana fought the war in human form. Vibhishana and his companions fought the war in the guise of humans.

It was a war strategy not to change the forms of Vanaras as a form of recognition among the vanaras.

Only *seven* fought the war in human form. (**[Thanks @TriyugiNarayanMani](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/43747052#43747052)**) They are

- Rama
- Lakshmana
- Vibhishana and his four companions.

> Monkeys should not assume human form in the battle, for, in the army of monkeys, this monkey-shape should serve as a sign of recognition among us. Among our own people also, the form of monkeys will become a sign of recognition for us. **Seven of us will attack the foe in our human form, I, my brother Lakshmana, who is full of valour, my friend Vibhishana and his four companions**.
>
> <sup>[Yuddha Kanda Sarga 37](http://valmikiramayan.net/utf8/yuddha/sarga37/yuddha_37_frame.htm)</sup>

Rama mentions Vibhishana and his companions as fighting in human form because Rakshasas are able to change their form by their will.

They met humans after the abduction of Sita. It is known from Ramayana. **They met Shabari** at the hermitage of  Matanga.

> On getting at that hermitage and on perusing at that picturesque environ that is wreathed round with several picturesque trees, those two came nigh of Shabari. On seeing them that sublimated yogi Shabari instinctively made palm-fold, got up imperatively, and then she braced the feet of Rama, and even that of sagacious Lakshmana, impressively.
>
> <sup>[Valmiki Ramayana Aranya Kanda Sarga 74](http://valmikiramayan.net/utf8/aranya/sarga74/aranya_74_frame.htm)</sup>

In Valmiki Ramayana she is only said as a sublimant yogi and an ardent devotee of Rama but in [later versions of Ramayana like Ranganatha Ramayana (Telugu) and Odia Ramyana](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/9127/5212), she is depicted to have utmost devotion towards him and offered fruits to Rama and Lakshmana. She tastes berries whether they are tasty enough and then gives tasty ones to Rama in Odia Ramayana.

Rama also met Sage Agastya (he is born of a pot and common son of devatas Mitra and Varuna though). He is the one who said Aditya Hridaya stotram to Rama for gaining victory over Ravana.

Comment: And matanga too as he had hermitage there.

Comment: @AnubhavJha The hermitage is indeed Matanga's but there is no mention of him meeting Rama and Lakshmana. He already heavens. Shabari also reached her preceptor. That is how it is said in the Valmiki Ramayana.